# Python moviepy's generating a weird video

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video, moviepy

I'm trying to add an audio track to a video track with Moviepy.
Here's the code :

```
videoClip = mp.VideoFileClip(os.path.join("VIDEOS", filename))
audioClip = mp.AudioFileClip(audio_file)
final = videoClip.set_audio(audioClip)
final.write_videofile(os.path.join("VIDEOS", filename), codec="mpeg4", 
audio_codec="libvorbis")
return filename
```

But the video has:

1. Bad quality
2. It gets stuck after about 0.5s

Also when Chrome opens it, it's opened as an audio file, even if it has .mp4 extension.

**Solution**:

1. Specify a higher bitrate
2. Change the video output file to another

```
final.write_videofile(os.path.join("VIDEOS", filename2), codec="mpeg4", audio_codec="libvorbis", bitrate="12000k")
```

Comment: You can't write into the same filename that you are reading from.

Comment: @TomBurrows It is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write into the same filename that you are reading from. *@Tom Burrows*